# ifstream, bytes read?

Tags: c++

How do you get how many bytes were read with the ifstream::read function?

Tell is saying the file is 10 bytes and windows says it is 10 bytes too but there are only 8 bytes in the file so when I read it, it is only reading the 8 bytes so I end up with too large of a buffer.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a newline at the end of the file (i.e., `\r\n` on Windows)? That would give you your missing two bytes.

Comment: Yes, tried it with fopen, etc and it returned only reading 8 bytes.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can find out by calling [`gcount()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) on a stream immediately after you read.

```
ifs.read(buf, sizeof buf);
std::streamsize bytes = ifs.gcount();
```

Comment: If gcount() did not read the exact requested, is the fstream object still in a valid state to continue and continue the read?

Answer (score 5):

There is a function called [`readsome(...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/readsome) that does what you want:

```
streamsize readsome ( char* s, streamsize n );
```

> Return Value The number of characters
>   extracted.

Comment: `readsome` only reads from the memory buffer associated with the stream, it won't necessarily read to the end of file even if the file is large enough. You don't want to use it except in very limited circumstances.